# How to do pagination in splash/scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to get items from website which has no next page href only numbers.I cannot get all pages, only one page.How can I modify my code and why I cannot get all items with my code? Can anyone explain?

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest 

class Hepsips4Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    #sayfaları otomatikleştir geçişi yapabilirsin
    name = 'hepsips4'
    allowed_domains = ['www.hepsiburada.com']
    script = '''

        function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(2))
        return {
        html = splash:html(),
        }
        end
          '''

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url="https://www.hepsiburada.com/playstation-4-oyunlari-c-60003893?siralama=enyeni&sayfa=1",callback=self.parse,endpoint="execute",args={'lua_source': self.script})

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in range(1,25):
            yield SplashRequest(url=f"https://www.hepsiburada.com/playstation-4-oyunlari-c-60003893?siralama=enyeni&sayfa={i}",callback=self.parse_item,endpoint="execute",args={'lua_source': self.script})

    def parse_item(self,response):
        for row in response.xpath("//ul[@class='product-list results-container do-flex list']/li/div"):
             name =row.xpath(".//a/div/h3/@title").get()
             img =row.xpath(".//a/figure/div/img/@data-src").get()
             company="hepsiburada"
             link =row.xpath(".//a/@href").get()
             fulllink=f"https://www.hepsiburada.com{link}"
             price =row.xpath(".//a/div/div[2]/span/text()").get()
             #sepet indirimini düzeltmeye çalış
             platform='ps4'
             yield{
                'name': name,
                'image': img,
                'company': company,
                'full_link': fulllink,
                'price': price,
                'platform': platform

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
script = '''

        function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(2))
        return {
        html = splash:html(),
        }
        end
          '''
```

Making waiting duration 2 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class JbPracujSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'jb_pracuj'
allowed_domains = ['www.pracuj.pl']

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(5))
        return {
            html = splash:html(),
        }
    end
        '''
def start_requests(self, headers=headers):
    yield SplashRequest(url='https://www.pracuj.pl/praca?rd=30&cc=5015%2c5016&pn=1', callback=self.parse, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 1})

def parse(self, response):
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield SplashRequest(url=f'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca?rd=30&cc=5015%2c5016&pn={i}', callback=self.parse_item, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 1})

def parse_item(self, response):
    for row in response.xpath("//li[@class='results__list-container-item']"):
        yield {
            'title': row.xpath(".//div[@class='offer-details__text']/h2/a[@class='offer-details__title-link']/text()|//div[@class='offer-details__text']/h2/button[@class='offer-details__title-link']/text()").get()
        }
```

and after execute this code i have a lot of None in my 'title' yield, but not everyone.